# Data Structure subject to Comparator

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, dictionary

I have defined class that maintains a sorted map of doubles maps that to other data structures. Depending on the use case I want that other to be in ascending or descending order.

```
struct Book {
  std::map<double, Level> levels;

  // More complexity ...

  void process(Tick &t);

  const unsigned amount;

  // More stuf ...

  Book(const unsigned amount) :  levels(), id_price() {}

};
```

Ideally, this should be specified in the constructor for Book. I could for example pass `std::less<double>()` but that won't work because I can't use variables to declare the map `levels`, right? Would it work with templates? I don't want to make it type generic. It should be doubles to not add unnecessary complexity. Ideas?

Comment: A template is probably the way to go.

Comment: Did you try anything already? Asking for _"Any ideas?"_ sounds too broad to be asked here. This may turn into an endless discussion which is what we don't want here. The site is rather about concise FAQ like question and answer pairs. You also may want to read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: You can parameterize on the compare type only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your map to use a custom comparator

```
struct Compare
{
    bool operator()(double l, double r) const {
        return cmp(l, r);
    }

    std::function<bool(double, double)> cmp;
};
```

Then you'd define your map as following:

```
std::map<double, Level, Compare> levels;
```

and the constructor

```
template<typename T>
Book(T comparator) :  levels(Compare{comparator}) {}
```

And then you can initialize your map with any comparator you would like

```
Book a(std::less<>{});
```

If you don't want the overhead of `std::function` you can implement more rigid logic right in your comparator.

Comment: Shouldn't the comparator be on double?

Comment: It should. Thanks! I guess the editbox doesn't make for a great IDE.

Comment: @joachim: using `Book a(std::less<>());` in this example hits [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). If you have more constructor arguments that cannot be misuonderstood the same way, then it's most likely fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a custom comparator along these lines:

```
class comparator {

public:

      bool descending;

      comparator(bool descending) : descending(descending) {}

      bool operator()(double a, double b) const
      {
            return descending ? b < a:a < b;
      }
};
```

Then, in your class, define your map specifying this comparator class:

```
std::map<double, Level, comparator> levels;
```

Your constructor then needs to explicitly initialize this comparator, and use it to initialize your class's map. `std::map`'s constructor takes an optional parameter, that passes an instance of the comparator class the map will use. Then, for each instance of your `Book`, its constructor can specify which way its `levels` will be sorted.

P.S. A `double` is a [poor choice for a map key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), but that would be a different question.